# Question regarding example of toric variety and generators of cone

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, toric-geometry

Consider the canonical example taking n=2, and taking the cone $\sigma$ generated by the vectors $e_{2}$ and $2e_{1} - e_{2}$. The dual cone $\sigma^{v}$ is defined as the set of vectors in the dual lattice $M$ s.t. they give a non-negative inner product on the cone $\sigma$. Now, referring to Fulton Introduction to Toric Varieties page 5, he states that the semigroup $S_{\sigma}$ is generated by the dual vectors $e_{1}^{*}, e_{1}^{*} + e_{2}^{*}$, and $e_{1}^{*} + 2e_{2}^{*}$.

My question is why isn't it sufficient for $S_{\sigma}$ to be generated by the dual vectors $e_{1}^{*}$ and $e_{1}^{*}+2e_{2}^{*}$ which are normal to the generators for $\sigma$? Why do we need the extra dual vector $e_{1}^{*} +e_{2}^{*}$ which is needed in order to show that this toric variety is isomorphic to the variety $V(xz-y^{2})$?

Additionally, is there an easy/intuitive way to see that the spectrum Spec($\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/[XZ-Y^{2}]$) gives a quadric cone?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on toric varieties, but if I recall correctly $S_{\sigma}$ is the additive semigroup of the points in the dual cone with non-negative integer coordinates. If this is the case, note that while $e_1^* + e_2^*$ is in $\sigma^{\vee}$, it cannot be obtained as $h e_1^* + k (e_1^* + 2e_2^*)$ with $h,k \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Similarly, the vector $e_1^* + 2e_2^*$ cannot be obtained as $h e_1^* + k (e_1^* + e_2^*)$. So you really need all three as generators.

Comment: Oh alright thanks. Is there an easy way to a prori see the generator $e_{1}^{*} + e_{2}^{*}$? The other ones are straightforward as they are simply the normals to the original generators.

Comment: There should be a formula to find all the generators (try looking in Cox's [tome](https://books.google.it/books?id=AoSDAwAAQBAJ)). On the other hand, you can just see that $e_1^* = e_2$, $e_2^* = - e_1$, and the slope of the ray through the point $(-2,1)$ is less than the slope of the ray through the point $(-1,1)$, so $e_1^* + e_2^*$ must be in the cone. This should become clear (possibly even intuitive) if you draw a picture of the cone and highlight the points with integer coordinates.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. Just one more thing, regarding my last question. Is there an intuitive way to picture the spectrum of the polynomial ring? I understand that the spectrum is the set of prime ideals, but how would one actually picture it geometrically, for example in this case as the quadric cone?

Comment: In general there is no way to picture the spectrum of a ring, at least faithfully. On the other hand, you can think of $\text{Spec}(R[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]/(f))$ as $V(f)$, which helps to get a rough idea. When $R$ is an algebraically closed field you don't really miss any point by looking just at the zero locus of $f$, at least when the variety is reduced. When picturing a complex variety, though, one can usually see only its real "trace" and has to imagine the rest. In your example, that's a [cone](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%5E2%20%2D%20x*z).